# Call base class method if not abstract

Tags: c++, templates, abstract

How to call base class method if it is not abstract.

```
class WithAbstMethod {
public:
    virtual void do() = 0;
}

class WithImplMethod : public WithAbstMethod {
public:
    virtual void do() {
        // do something
    }
}

template<typename BaseT>
class DerivedClass : BaseT {
public:
    virtual void do() {
        BaseT::do(); // here is a question. How to modify code, so that do() is called if it is not abstract?
        // do something
    }
}

void main() {
    DerivedClass<WithAbstMethod> d1;
    d1.do(); // only DerivedClass::do() should be called
    DerivedClass<WithImplMethod> d2;
    d2.do(); // both WithImplMethod::do() and DerivedClass::do() should be called
}
```

Is it possible to do this using templates in compile-time without much code (instantiate DerivedClass::do() method with BaseT::do() call and without depending on BaseT type)?
Obviously, provide implementation in WithAbstMethod class is not an option. Code above is pseudo-code so may contain minor errors.

Comment: Note that `do` is a reserved word in C++ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, providing an implementation for `WithAbstMethod::do()` might be an option.  Abstract functions are allowed to have an implementation.

```
void WithAbstMethod::do()
{
    // do nothing...
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean. This method should be abstract by design. So I want compile-time error in such code: void main() { WithAbstMethod a1; }

Comment: Well, you should get a compile-time error for `void main()` already. That aside, if `WithAbstMethod::do()` is abstract, you still get a compile-time error if you implemented it! Ah - you didn't notice that you can implement abstract members, I guess: you can! `struct A { void B() = 0; }; void A::B() {}` This is an abstract class `A` with an implemented abstract function `A::B()`. This could e.g. be useful in your case.

Comment: The compiler won't let you instantiate an abstract class (in other words, leave the `=0` in the function declaration). But, you're still permitted to have an implementation for the abstract function that derived classes can call. For `void` functions that can work nicely and easily; it might not fit as well if you have abstract functions that would have to return something and there's no sensible 'default'.

Comment: Wow, that's probably best answer so far at least because of new knowledge :). However I would still eager to find solution where the call to pure virtual method isn't even compiled.